# NHibernate.Linq LIKE

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

How can I produce this query using NHibernate.Linq?

```
WHERE this_.Name LIKE @p0; @p0 = 'test'  // Notice NO % wild card
```

Note, this is not Linq To Sql or Entity Framework. This is NHibernate.

**Edit:**

Here is the desired query using ICriteria:

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Like("Name", "test"));
return criteria.List<Theater>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With NH 4 (and probably a bit earlier), a built-in `Like` string extension is available within `NHibernate.Linq` namespace: `Like(this string matchExpression, string sqlLikePattern)`. (It is defined on [`NHibernate.Linq.SqlMethods`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/SqlMethods.cs) extension class.)

```cs
using NHibernate.Linq;
...
session.Query<Theater>()
    .Where(t => t.Name.Like("test"));
```

Answer (score 28):

Whilst this has been marked as resolved, which was correct at the time, may I also note that NHibernate has some extensions now so you can do the following:

```
Session.QueryOver<MyEntity>()
    .Where(x => x.Property.IsLike("something", MatchMode.Anywhere))
    .List();
```

This will do a `LIKE '%something%'` for you.

Comment: These are out-the-box, by the way, not custom built.

Comment: +1 exactly what I was looking for, might be worth noting to solve the exact problem above you'd want to use MatchMode.Exact (no % wildcard)

Comment: Had to add a `using NHibernate.Criterion;` when not using Resharper.  But works great!  Thanks.

Comment: The question is about Linq to NHibernate, not about Query over.

Answer (score 18):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var theaters = from theater in Session.Linq<Theater>() 
               where theater.Name.Contains("test") 
               select theater;
```

According to my tests it generates an SQL 'LIKE' statement: 
"... WHERE theater.Name LIKE %test%"

which is exactly the output of the criteria snippet you have provided.

Comment: Using Criteria (provided in the question), I am not seeing the % wildcards being generated.

Comment: I have just ran the unit test that I have with the code provided in my answer and it produced a SQL statement with the % wildcard in both ends on the serch string.
I also run the same test using the Criteria equilevant and I get the exact same SQL statement if I use criteria.Add(Expression.Like("Name", "test", MatchMode.Anywhere));

I use NHibernate 2.1 with SQL Server 2005.
If you are using the same configuration then you should be able to see the same results.

Comment: The issue is I don't want the wildcards using Linq. My comment above this was responding to your answer "exactly the output of the criteria snippet you have provided". Sorry if I was not clear. I can achieve the desired query with ICriteria as stated in the Question, but cannot seem to achieve it using Linq.

Comment: So you want to generate a LIKE statment WITHOUT the % around your search string. As you say you are doing that already with Criteria but you want to achieve the same with LINQ. I apologise for misreading your initial comment... Can I ask why would someone want to do that? I believe the LIKE operator without wildcards is the same or at least is optimised to be the same as using the '=' operator.

Comment: Yes, that is my question.  The reason why is given the criteria LIKE 'test' returns values with 'TEST' and not 'TESTEST'. Or in other words 'Test' != 'test'.  So basically its for ignoring case only. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem in my project and found a solution :

```
session.Linq<Theater>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("test") && x.Name.EndsWith("test");
```

This translates in SQL to

```
SELECT ... WHERE Name LIKE '%test' AND Name LIKE 'test%'
```

Comment: addition: `&& x.Name.Length == "test".Length`. otherwise you'd end up with results like `test blah blah blah test`

Comment: I may be missing the point, but surely you aren't really doing a 'like' but an 'equals' ... .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("test");

Comment: It's indeed as @n3rd said.

Comment: This will not work if the search text is in the middle. For example, if you type in "cks", the word "Jackson" will not come up.

Comment: I know. The question pertained to a LIKE without wildcards. Check his comment on the first line.